# Javascript equivalent of Python's locals()?

Tags: javascript, python

In Python one can get a dictionary of all local and global variables in the current scope with the built-in functions `locals()` and `globals()`.  Is there some equivalent way of doing this in Javascript?  For instance, I would like to do something like the following:

```
var foo = function(){ alert('foo'); };
var bar = function(){ alert('bar'); };

var s = 'foo';
locals()[s](); // alerts 'foo'
```

Is this at all possible, or should I just be using a local object for the lookup?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- locals() - No.
- globals() - Yes.

`window` is a reference to the global scope, like `globals()` in python.

```
globals()["foo"]
```

is the same as:

```
window["foo"]
```

Comment: Only in a browser or other host environment that implements *window*.

Comment: That's true. There isn't any way to do this in Node for example? I guess it should be changes then, as this is a general JavaScript answer.

Comment: when there is no *window*, there is *global* - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10984629/596361

Comment: this works only on top level scope. what if I want to call it from inner scope?

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't think that there is something like that in js. You can always use eval instead of locals(). Like this:

```
eval(s+"()");
```

You just have to know that actually function *foo* exists.

**Edit:**

Don't use eval:) Use:

```
var functionName="myFunctionName";
window[functionName]();
```

Comment: Using the window object, only gives you access to globals, not to local variables.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to remember Brendan Eich commented on this in a recent podcast; if i recall correctly, it's not being considered, as it adds unreasonable restrictions to optimization. He compared it to the `arguments` local in that, while useful for varargs, its very existence removes the ability to guess at what a function will touch just by looking at its definition.

BTW: i believe JS *did* have support for accessing locals through the arguments local at one time - [a quick search](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions/arguments) shows this has been deprecated though.

Answer (score 1):

@e-bartek, I think that window[functionName] won't work if you in some closure, and the function name is local to that closure.  For example:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = function () {
        alert('hello world');
    };
    var s = 'bar';
    window[s](); // this won't work
}
```

In this case, s is 'bar', but the function 'bar' only exists inside the scope of the function 'foo'.  It is not defined in the window scope.

Of course, this doesn't really answer the original question, I just wanted to chime in on this response.  I don't believe there is a way to do what the original question asked.

Answer (score 0):

@pkaeding

Yes, you're right. *window[functionName]()* doesn't work in this case, but *eval* does. If I needed something like this, I'd create my own object to keep those functions together.

```
var func = {};
func.bar = ...;
var s = "bar";
func[s]();
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, no. If you just want to check the existence of a given variable, you can do it by testing for it, something like this:

```
if (foo) foo();
```

Comment: That will only work if the variable has been defined, otherwise it will throw a ReferenceError.