# How to get local variable by its name in JS?

Tags: javascript

Working example with global var:

```
var example_var = 'global var example';

var x = function(){
    var var_name = 'example_var';
    alert('Global var value is: ' + window[var_name]);
}
```

How can I do same thing with a local variable? Like this (not working example):

```
var x = function(){
    var example_var = 'Local var example';
    var var_name = 'example_var';
    alert('Local var value is: ' + window[var_name]);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960/javascript-locals

Comment: Why? This is usually a sign of dealing with variables the hard way.

Comment: It's clean example of problem.
In fact, this code is used to extend objects by different methods, whose names are contained in the objects themselves.

Comment: @oswork: There's no function-scope object you can access from regular Javascript to extend, so that problem doesn't apply here. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Get local variable dynamically by name string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920867/javascript-get-local-variable-dynamically-by-name-string)

Comment: @Anonymous “Why?” Because it is an easy way to access arbitrary variables from an obfuscated closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use `eval`; a locally scoped object might be your best option:

```
var x = function(){
    var self = {};
    self.example_var = 'Local var example';

    var var_name = 'example_var';

    alert('Local var value is: ' + self[var_name]);
}
```

Comment: This is a workaround (a good one), but does not strictly answer the question.

Comment: This is useless if the code is out of your control (in other words, “_obfuscated_.”).

Answer (score 7):

If you have no other way, you can try `eval` it

```
var x = function(){
    var example_var = 'Local var example';
    var var_name = 'example_var';
    alert('Local var value is: ' + eval(var_name));
}
```

Comment: This, `eval`, [collecting local variables with a `with` statement and a `Proxy` scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41704827/4510033), and [analyzing the function body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25473571/4510033), would be more or less the only solutions.

Answer (score -4):

possibly:

```
var x = function(){
    var example_var = 'Local var example';
    var var_name = example_var;
    alert('Local var value is: ' + var_name);
}
```

or:

```
  var x = function(){
        var example_var = 'Local var example';
       window.var_name = example_var;
        alert('Local var value is: ' + window[var_name]);
    }
```

or

```
  var x = function(){
            var var_name = 'Local var example';    
            alert('Local var value is: ' + var_name);
        }
```

Comment: Question is about to access variable by name. Your examples: 1) var_name value is "example_var" not the value of the example_var 2) Still var_name contain the name of the varible not it's value 3) there is no other variable you try to access.

Answer (score -4):

At the moment there are two solutions to this problem.
1. eval(), but i really don't like to use evil()
2. we can change variable declaration from var to this:

```
var x = function(){
    this.example_var = 'this.var example';
    this.var_name = 'example_var';
    alert('Local variable value is: ' + this[var_name]);
}
```

Comment: Often, `this` will be equivalent to `window`, so that may obliterate globals.