# call or access a local function by name

Tags: javascript

```
function f1 () {
    console.log('f1')
}

var s = 'f1'

runLocalFunctionByName(s)
```

Is this possible at all to write `runLocalFunctionByName()` or just call `f1` without typing `f1` in the source code, but using a variable holding its name? I mean without modifying `f1` into a method, that answer is obvious: just make `myobj.f1 = function` or declare it globally like `f1= function()`. I am talking about normal local functions declared with `function` keyword only, not as vars, global vars or some other object property.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I suspect this is an XY problem, and there's a better way to solve it.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146173/how-to-get-local-variable-by-its-name-in-js, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598878/how-can-i-access-local-scope-dynamically-in-javascript.

Comment: `f1` is not a local function here--by "local" do you mean that it is defined inside some other function?

Answer (score 4):

Not without the use of `eval`, which is evil (when used for this purpose for sure!).

Global functions could be called as attributes of the `window` object, but if they are in a local/closure scope that's not possible.

If you need to call functions by name, the only proper solution is storing them as attributes on an object, and then using `obj[s]()` for calling them.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by using the instantiating a Function object.

```
var runLocalFunctionByName = function(fName) { 
    return (new Function('','return '+fName+'();'))(); 
};
```

Calling runLocalFunctionByName with a name of a function will now return the output of the named function.

**EDIT**

In case of local functions, the scope has to be mentioned, so we can modify the code, such that:

```
var runLocalFunctionByName = function(fName, scope) { 
    return (new Function('','return '+(scope?scope:'this')+'.'+fName+'();'))(); 
};
```

Comment: That will only work for global functions, not local ones.

Comment: Yes. In that case, we can modify this code to include the scope for the local functions.

Comment: How? Show that please, it is what was asked for.

Comment: And what would you pass as `scope` in OPs example?

Comment: It's a poor idea to propose this semi-eval-ish solution without understanding what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a local function outside its scope until unless you assign it to a variable having an accessible scope. [MDN: A function defined by a function expression inherits the current scope. That is, the function forms a closure. On the other hand, a function defined by a Function constructor does not inherit any scope other than the global scope (which all functions inherit)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Comment: He's not worried about scoping. He's trying to call a function when what he has is its name in string form.