# how to refer a global variable value inside a local function with the same variable name

Tags: javascript

In the following code snippet how can we refer the global variable `x` values as `product` in the eval function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 'product';
window.onload = function() {
    function somefunction() {
        var x = 'boat';
        alert(eval('x'));
    }
    somefunction();
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146173/how-to-get-local-variable-by-its-name-in-js?rq=1

Comment: There isn't a global variable `x` in that example code.

Comment: And don't do that. Give your variables sensible, non-conflicting names instead.

Comment: The solution is simple: don't overwrite your variable names. Since the name resolution is entirely lexical, that shouldn't be much of a problem to implement.

Comment: @Quentin I understand its not a good practice. I just wanted to clarify the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window` object to make your variable global and use `window.x` to access it.

```js
var x = 'product';

function somefunction() {
  var x = 'boat';
  console.log("logging global variable window.x: "+eval('window.x')); // resolve conflicts by using window.x
}
somefunction();

console.log("logging global variable x: "+ x); // access global variable..
```

So the changes you need to apply will be only when you want `to resolve conflicts`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks I updated my answer, I initially tried in `jsFiddle` with `var x` but then the `window.x` showed undefined. Now I realize it was because if `jsfiddle` the code runs inside an `iframe`

Comment: That's not why. It's because of jsFiddle's <s>stupid</s> *surprising* default of wrapping your code in a `window.onload = function() { ... };` handler.

Comment: oh I get it.. I use it because even this code snippet of SO has lot of bugs.. I have lost my work many times

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways :-

1. You can store the global version of variable , associated with a **global level object** like :-

`var globalObject.x = "foo";
    function test(){
     x = "bar";
     console.log(x); // it will print the local reference of x // "bar"
     console.log(globalObject.x); // it will print the global level x // "foo"
    }`

2. You can use -  '**this**' variable

`var self = this;
        x = "foo";
        function test(){
           x = "bar";
         console.log(x); // it will print the local reference of x // "bar"
         console.log(self.x); // it will print the global level x // "foo"
        }`