# Variable contents as name of a variable

Tags: c#

Something I've always wondered how to do in C# is exactly as the title describes; To use the value of a variable/string as the name/accessor of another variable.

The easiest way to visualize this is as a simple perl script:

```
$string = "unknown until runtime";
$TargetVariableName = "string";
print $$TargetVariableName; //in actuality this reads as print $string, notice double $$
// outputs: unknown until runtime
```

Is there an easy way to do this in c# without utilizing reflection's gettype().getproperty().getvalue() stuff?- Am hoping for a short and elegant method to accomplish this.

(Once you've gotten used to the functionality, suddenly you're aware of many ways it could be useful in shortening the time it takes to write code.. It's also useful for dynamically creating and accessing objects)

Comment: There is rarely a need to do this in C#. If you feel the need to do this, most of the time (not always) this is a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and there exists a better solution for your actual problem. The few times that doing this is not an XY problem, you use reflection. So, please explain the actual problem you are trying to solve by doing this, and, why don't you like reflection?

Comment: "Once you've gotten used to the functionality, suddenly you're aware of many ways it could be useful in shortening the time it takes to write code." I could say the same for C#. Once you've gotten used to the other functionalities that C# has to solve *whatever problem you are actually solving*, suddenly you're aware of many ways *insert C# feature here* could be useful in shortening the time it takes to write code.

Comment: @Sweeper note that there is no way to get variable values by reflection... I don't think what OP is asking is solvable in any way in C# (unlike getting fields or properties by name which at least solvable with reflection as you likely meant to say)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Not *local* variables yeah. The [spec's definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#91-general) includes anything that can be assigned to. That wasn't the point of the comment anyway :)

Comment: Actually now I'm wondering which language actually does support such functionality (besides maybe python's `locals`)... One would guess that JavaScript would be such language, but not really unless you go down to `eval` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146173/how-to-get-local-variable-by-its-name-in-js)... May be an interesting [edit] to the post to show what language OP is looking to imitate.

Answer (score 2):

C# is a compiled language and as such referencing variable value by variable name is not a first class citizen, even though it's possible.

for interpreted languages, it's actually using a concept of a map to hold values and variables to begin with.

So to do something similar to interpreted languages your would use C#'s analogue of a map:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string,string>();
// fill the values
values["foo"] = "bar";
values["string"] = "barbar";
var name = "string"; // get the name you are looking for
Console.WriteLine(values[name]); // here the value will be looked up by name. in this case it would print "barbar" because that's the value of the "string" key.
```

It's possible to find a value of a variable by it's name, but it's generally unreasonable unless for some class library developers, since production code may be obfuscated (all variables renamed) and variables are not created dynamically anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your lines of code (commented out) with legal C# taking their place.

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//$string = "unknown until runtime";
string @string = "unknown until runtime";

map["string"] = @string;

//$TargetVariableName = "string";
string targetVariableName = "string";
    
//print $$TargetVariableName;
Console.WriteLine(map[targetVariableName]);
```

That outputs:

```
unknown until runtime
```