# What is the value of 'this' returned from arrow function on an object literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

What is the value of **this** returned from an arrow function on an object literal when running in nodejs. This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645925/es6-in-nodejs-arrow-functions-in-object-literal-what-is-the-returned-this-va) however the answer is just not correct in nodejs. It is not global and it is not **undefined** in strict mode.

Here is the code snippet that I'm running:

```
"use strict";  // <-- Has no affect.
let a = {
  f: () => this
};

console.log(a.f())                          // {}
console.log(a.f() === global);              // false
console.log(a.f() === {});                  // false
console.log(a.f() === Object.create(null)); // false
```

Update:

Another way to illustrate what I'm seeing, run this at your command prompt:

```
node -e "let a = { f: () => this }; console.log( a.f() === global);"  // returns true
```

Now, copy the contents of the code in the string above into a **script.js** and run via:

```
node script.js  // returns false
```

Comment: Your comparisons to `{}` and `Object.create(null)` will never be `true` because a newly created object can never be the same as some other object, since they’re compared by reference.

Comment: `a.f() === global` is [`true` for me](https://repl.it/J3bT).

Comment: @4castle Interesting! Could you by chance run that in your local node and see if you get the same?

Comment: My local node is version 4.5.0 and has the same result.

Comment: I just updated to version 8.1.4 and also get `true` for being the global object.

Comment: Could this possibly be OS dependent? I was running the above code on MacOS with various node versions and get the above results on all versions.  However, I just fired up a VM running lubuntu and node v4.2.6 and **a.f()** does return **global**.

Comment: @4castle are you on linux?

Comment: I was running it on Windows 10. I also just tried it on Ubuntu with v4.2.6 and got `global` again. It could just be on MacOS, but I don't have access to that.

Comment: Something else odd. When I type the above code in the node REPL on MacOS, **a.f()** does return **global**. Running it via the node executable on both MacOS and Linux, it returns **{}**.

Comment: Value of `this` keyword is variable and depends on how a function is called. In case of arrow functions the function remembers the context in which it was defined. `this` in node modules seems to be a plain object. Also note that in JavaScript `{} !== {}` (2 different objects are not equal!)

Comment: @undefined What's a mystery to me though is that we're calling it in exactly the same way in both cases, yet, it yields **global** in one case and a plain object **{}** in the other.

Comment: That's because the the contexts are different. Your code effectively has no difference with `console.log(this)`. Your question actually should be: What does this refer to in local context of node modules. this seems to be a plain object. See the sandbox option of the following method of the vm module which is used by require for executing modules: https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_options. It says that the context will be a new object when there is no specified context.

Comment: @undefined Aha, **thank you**, this is starting to make sense to me now, let me see if I understand. So, in the REPL, it creates a `this` context (`global`) for you when you fire it up.  But, when running via a script with just a `console.log(this)`, `this` has not been created yet hence node creates the empty object. This is why if you type `this` in the REPL you see `global` but if you run an script with a `console.log(this)`, you get a `{}`. Am I on the right line of thinking here?