# Concatenating variables in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
.Contents
        -for(var i = 1; i < length; i++)
          .QuestionFrame
            =(i+1) + ') ' + ti.FAQ_QUESTION
          .AnswerFrame
            =ti.FAQ_DESCRIPTION
```

In this code, I am tying to make variables looking like t1.FAQ_QUESTION, t2.FAQ_QUESTION, t3.FAQ_QUESTION, and so on. I have no idea how to concatenate t and i to make a single variable.

Comment: Are you trying to render the `FAQ_QUESTION` property of the `t1` object?

Comment: @Sean Yes FAQ_QUESTION property of the t1, t2, t3, t4... to where the for loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Contents
        each topic in topics
          .QuestionFrame
            =topic.FAQ_ID + ') '
            =topic.FAQ_QUESTION
          .AnswerFrame
            =topic.FAQ_DESCRIPTION
          br
```

for each loop helped me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117172/5351721) to a question about [using dynamic variable names in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript), all variables declared in the global context (outside of a function context), can be accessed as properties of the Global object. And because they're accessible as properties, you can use concatenation within [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

It's important to point out that the examples given in the answer above are for javascript that runs in the *browser*. The Global object for javascript in browsers is the `window` object.

However, Pug runs in Node—not the browser. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10984638/5351721) to a different question about [What is the node.js equivalent of window[“myvar”] = value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984629/what-is-the-node-js-equivalent-of-windowmyvar-value) notes that the Global object in Node is `global`.

So you should be able to do something like this in Pug:

```
.Contents
  - for(var i = 1; i < length; i++)
    - let qa = global['t' + i]
    .QuestionFrame= qa.FAQ_QUESTION
    .AnswerFrame= qa.FAQ_DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but maybe due to the less information given, qa.FAQ_QUESTION, qa.FAQ_DESCRIPTION is still undefined.

Comment: ```
app.get('/faq.jade',function(req,res){
    var sql = 'SELECT FAQ_QUESTION, FAQ_DESCRIPTION from faq';
    connection.query(sql, function(err, topics, fields){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error(faq.jade)');
      }else{
        var faq_content = { length : topics.length
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < topics.length; i++){
          faq_content['t'+(i+1)] = topics[i]
        }
        console.log(faq_content);
        res.render('faq.jade', faq_content);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @chachacha please edit your question to include this code. it's hard to parse as a comment without formatting.