# Create dictionary of local variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I realize there is no way to get a [dictionary of local variables in a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope), and no [equivalent of python's locals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-locals). However, is there a way to write a function that would assist in this. For example, something like:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

var output = locals(a, b);
console.log(output);
```

And output would be a dictionary with all the variables:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
}
```

Or, any other way apart from me manually creating a map, and inserting each field.

Comment: Can you use array for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276206/list-all-js-global-variables-used-by-site-not-all-defined

Comment: As the questions you link to say: No. JS provides no mechanisms for inspecting what variables exist (other than globals when they are added to the default object as a side-effect)

Comment: If you are going to make a static function call, referencing the variables, you can use the short property syntax of the object literal: `const output = { a, b }`

Comment: @Quentin, I am not asking to inspect the variables in scope. I understand that is not possible. I am asking if there is a way to create a helper method to assist with creating a dictionary of specified local variables. The method will be passed all the variables of interest. So, this question is not really a duplicate.

Comment: @CMS, thats pretty nifty. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Since you can't pass variables (only values) the data passed to such a function would be `1` and `2` with no association with the variable name.

You can, however, use the shorthand object syntax:

```
const output = { a, b };
```

… where an identifier without a value will take its value from the variable of the same name.